# Grub2 installation error

Tags: grub2

I am attempting to install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS server edition on an old Dell xps 410. It has two hard drives in a RAID configuration. I keep getting a fatal error when installing grub boot loader. It is looking for a Device for boot loader installation. How do I determined what command to use? I've tried /dev/sda, /dev/sda1 through 5, /dev/hd00, /dev/hd01, /dev/fd0, /dev/sdb, /dev/sdc. How do I determined what my number one hard drive path is?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my own problem. I removed the RAID configuration. Not the most elegant solution, but it worked never the less.